# How to hash a JWT signature using Public & private key (Have both key in JSON format & X.509 PEM Format), using ES256 algo for JWT

Tags: hash-signature, jwt

I want to **hash my signature of JWT using public & private key**, since we are using ES-256 algorithm in JWT. But the problem is that I have both the keys in JSON & .PEM format, so how can I do it in one openssl command? below is the shell script code which I am using to hash the signature:

`SIGNATURE=$(echo -n "$DATA" | openssl dgst -binary -sha256 -hmac "$SECRET"| openssl base64 -e -A | sed 's/=//g' | sed 's/\+/-/g' | sed 's/\//_/g')`

The problem over here is that the variable "$SECRET" need to have both private & public key. So could anyone help me with this. Thanks in advance!

NOTE : The variable $DATA is concatenation of header & payload encrypted in base64, required for JWT authentication.

Comment: Using an asymmetric-key cryptography "key-pair" with a symmetric-key HMAC is definitely a sign that you got something wrong.

Comment: @DannyNiu : Thanks for your comment!... Could you please provide any asymmetric way of signing the JWT token instead of using HMAC?

Comment: The signing operation involves the signing private key. In JOSE, the [key usage](https://www.iana.org/assignments/jose/jose.xhtml#web-key-use) should be `sig`, and [key type](https://www.iana.org/assignments/jose/jose.xhtml#web-key-types) should be EC, RSA, or OKP depending on your algorithm.

Comment: @DannyNiu : Thanks for your comment!..We already have a private key with key usage "sig" and key type as "EC"..generated from the portal "https://mkjwk.org/". But the problem which we are having is signing the hashed message with this key..We are using the below code:
`Openssl dgst -sha256 -sign private_key.pem -out signature.sig data_tst.txt`
The file data_tst.txt contain the concatenate header(base64URL)+”.”+payload(base64URL). But this signature is not getting verified in "https://jwt.io/" portal. I am not sure if there is any other method in openssl to sign using ECDSA key P-256 curve

Comment: Format also matters. OpenSSL probably outputs in DER-encoded ASN.1 SEQUENCE structure, where as JOSE uses simple concatenation.

Comment: @DannyNiu : Thanks for your comment! Do you happen to know how to change the format of the signature file generated by openssl into the JOSE format??

Comment: I've never used JOSE in pactice so I'm not sure. The general idea is that you parse the OpenSSL output using some ASN.1 parser, then truncate the 2 INTEGER elements to 32 bytes (for P-256, or 48 bytes for P-384), then concatenate them. I've heard of asn1c, and [this command-line tool](https://github.com/phish108/node-jose-tools), but never used them. You'll have to work on this part yourself, or consult StackOverflow.